# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty. when connecting to Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect to Azure Active Directory with my application, but I'm getting this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null
>   or empty. Unknown location
>
> AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__5.MoveNext()

My appsettings.json file looks like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "<Application ID value from Azure Portal>",
    "AadInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
    "TenantId": "<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "AuthCallback": "/"
  }
```

and in Startup.cs

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication();

  app.UseIdentity();
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
  {
       ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"],
       Authority = string.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]),
       CallbackPath = Configuration["AzureAd:AuthCallback"]
  });
```

I've enabled ssl in my project, and added the url that Visual Studio gives me as the reply URL.

Before, when I had an incorrect URL configured, it led me to the Microsoft login site that said that the URL didn't match any registered ones, so I know it at least got that far.

I should also say that I was following [this post](https://joonasw.net/view/asp-net-core-1-azure-ad-authentication), but using the new portal. I don't have access to the classic portal.

How can I resolve this error?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mentioned the new portal please ensure it means the [new Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com/)
instead of [new register apps portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2F) which for [Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview).

> Before, when I had an incorrect URL configured, it led me to the Microsoft login site that said that the URL didn't match any registered ones, so I know it at least got that far.

The redirect_url you using in the code should be configed for the apps you register on Azure.

And I also followed this link and the project works well for me. You can download the project from [here](https://github.com/VitorX/webapp-core-aad-scratch). Please config the redirect_url(https://localhost:44397/signin-aad) for the app on the Azure first and set the appsetting based on your app, then you can access the app using the Url https://localhost:44397

Answer (score 2):

If someone runs into this, add an event handler to OnMessageReceived to debug requests. Somehow i stumbled into setting the redirect_url to /signin-oidc and a GET on that path will have an empty context.Properties which is ofcourse resulting into this specific error

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: This answer should be up in lights.  I was implementing an Account Controller to perform the challenge and did something like this:  var ret = this.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/signin-oidc" }, $"{OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}");  Of course I should have just used RedirectUri = "/"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's related but I just ran into a similar issue with a similar error message. @rfcdejong pointed me in the right direction by suggesting to debug `OnMessageReceived`. In my case I was trying to implement a reset password custom flow in Azure AD B2C. It was calling this with only an id_token. This lead me to realise I should redirect the user to the home page at this point - otherwise I also got a `message.State is null or empty` error.

My code looks like this:
Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomOpenIdConnectEvents);
});
```

and then in CustomOpenIdConnectEvents I have:

```
    public class CustomOpenIdConnectEvents : OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        ...

        public override async Task MessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
        {
            // Set breakpoint in here to see what is happening

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.Error) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription))
            {
                if (context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.StartsWith("AADB2C90118")) // forgot password
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // On successful password reset we need to do this or we get a message.State is null or empty
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            }

            return;// Task.FromResult(0);

        }
```

It might be worth noting that I do this a little differently to most people. Usually you won't override the entire EventsType with a custom object that inherits from `OpenIdConnectEvents`. Instead you might do it like this, all in the Startup.cs file:

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options => 
{

    // ...

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("error"))
            {
                context.HandleResponse(); // <-- Fires
                context.Response.Redirect("/AccessDenied"); // <-- Redirect fires but user is not redirected
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And, if debugging `OnMessageReceived` doesn't help you may like to try `OnRemoteFailure` or `OnAuthenticationFailed` as well.